# Can a splitview be loaded inside the detail view of another splitview?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am trying to develop an application that has screen flow similar to oracle app. I have attached the images here. Can anyone please tell how this can be achieved ?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a custom Split View Controller. The screenshots you provided are of custom split view controllers. The UIKit has `UISplitViewController` but this must be a fullscreen view controller.

To make a custom split view controller there's the old way, by having a main view controller and making your two master and detail controllers, adding their view to the main view controllers view.
You need to forward on calls from `viewWillAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear:` etc from the main view controller to the two controllers that you manage.

As of iOS 5, you can do something similar with view controller containment, this has a few more bells and whistles, more interesting it handles rotation animations better and all the call forwarding to the children controllers that you had to do manually in the first solution.

Check out this link for more details on custom split view controllers:
http://www.mindtreatstudios.com/how-its-made/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-ios/

To answer your question directly: if you make a custom split view controller - yes you can add this as a detail view controller. But watch out, this isn't a `UISplitViewController`, so just be careful not to use that term so much.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't really tested this, but doesn't this solve your problem?

- Create a storyboard file
- Drop in a SplitViewController
- Delete the DetailViewController
- Drop in another SplitViewController
- Link the two together using CTRL-drag and select Detail
- Set the size of the detail-splitviewcontroller to Detail
- ????
- Profit!

Anyways, not sure if it really works, but give it a try. This is IOS5 though (I think, might try it out with IB).

It'll look something like this:

[image: SplitSplitViewControllers]

Comment: This does not work because when you run it, you will get an error `Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller <UINavigationController: 0x105831600>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have to write your own class, you might want to first look at https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController for inspiration.